When the Authorization is in Setup Thread group, only getting partial value of Authorization is getting of a request under the Thread group
I am facing the below issue
I have captured the Authorization part of Login Requests, which has bunch of values and saved into the CSV file and passing to the following Requests.
Here is the Test Plan
Access Token CSV File
Set Up Thread Group
Include Controller( Login test Fragment)

Thread Group
Requests

 Header Manager - has Authorization

Issue: When Run the above for the Requests under Main Thread group getting the partial value i.e Authorization: {"userId":5739
After  , not captured the rest of the values, If you observe I have mentioned the File encoding: UTF-8 so should not be problem after , also should picked up the rest of eth value's. Tried Sharing Mode: All Threads did not work.
But When I Moved  the Include Controller( Login test Fragment) to under the Main Thread Group it works





Tried to Pass Authorization using JSR2233 PreProcsseer Header, no luck still passed the truncated Authorization
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

 
// Read the entire line from the CSV file
String authorization = vars.get("captured_login_responsebody_admin");

if (authorization == null || authorization.isEmpty()) {
    log.error("Authorization is missing or empty!");
} else {
    log.info("Authorization  from CSV: " + authorization);
    
    // Ensure the sampler is an instance of HTTPSamplerBase (which it should be for HTTP requests)
    if (sampler instanceof HTTPSamplerBase) {
        // Add the Authorization header
        sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Authorization");
        sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization", authorization));
        log.info("Authorization header set: " + authorization);
    } else {
        log.error("Sampler is not an instance of HTTPSamplerBase!");
    }
}


If the values you're extracting contain comma you will need to:

Set "Allow quoted data" to True in the CSV Data Set Config


Add quotation marks around the values somehow and add another quotation marks if the field contains quotation mark



I have tried that already earlier thrown the ERROR o.a.j.c.CSVDataSet: java.io.IOException: Cannot have quote-char in plain field:[{"]
